# How can I call Model::save() using a custom primary key in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.x

I want to update a record:

```
//Update: id is set to a numerical value
$this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->data);
```

This is working fine.

But it won't work if I try to update the record based on `tmp_id`:

```
$this->Recipe->tmp_id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->data);
```

I am aware of function `Model::updateAll()`. But I want to use `Model::save()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$this->Recipe->primaryKey = 'tmp_id';
$this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->data);
```

Or you could make changes permanent by defining `tmp_id` as the primary key in your Model:

```
class Recipe extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = 'tmp_id';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update statement in cakephp** :

```
public function update_data($tmp_id){

if($this->request->is('post'){

$this->Recipe->id = $tmp_id;
$this->Recipe->save($this->data);

}

}
```

Here update_data is **Dummy function** for your understanding.